# Undefined variable en PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Que tal compañeros necesito de su gran ayuda, llevo paliando contra un error que me tiene agobiado desde hace muchas horas y no lo puedo solucionar antes me funcionaba pero formatos mi pc y ya no funciona, me manda error cuando intento crear un listado para cada trabajador y manda error cuando inserto datos, el error es por la imagen pero he intentado de todo y no se soluciona, no se insertan los registros en MySQL.
Les agradeceré toda la vida, Muchas Gracias! :)

Este es el código insertar donde manda error...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí esta el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 y este es el error que sale en PHP
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y debería salir asi…

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Sería de más ayuda que pusieras el texto del código en la pregunta que una imagen. Las variables parece que no están declaradas más para arriba. **¿Dónde las declaras y les asignas algún valor?**

Comment: Ok. Las variables en PHP sólo son visibles en el ámbito de su función. Entonces tú declaras la variable en `subirImagen()`, pero no puedes usarla fuera de esa función, a no ser que la envíes desde su ámbito a través de un `return $nombre_img;` colocado en la **última línea** de la función. En ese caso, en la línea del error deberías poner esto antes de usar la variable: `$nombre_img=subirImagen();` O si estuvieras dentro de una `Clase`. Es necesario que organices el código mejor, en una clase, o haciendo que `subirImagen()` te retorne las variables que quieres usar fuera de ella.

Comment: Prueba poniendo un var_dump($nombre_img); arriba de $db->insertar... Actualizas el post con lo que te muestre el navegador y a ver si se puede resolver.

Comment: Ok voy a intentarlo Muchas Gracias!
Y tendré en cuenta lo del código la próxima vez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás ante un problema de *ámbito* de las funciones/variables de PHP.

La variable que quieres usar está aquí:

```
function subirImagen() {

    $nombre_img="...";

    //código

}
```

**Tú no puedes usarla fuera de ahí**, a no ser que la retornes desde dentro de la función.

En ese caso, tendrías que poner un `return` al final:

```
function subirImagen() {

    $nombre_img="...";

    //código

    /*Esta debe ser la última línea*/
    return $nombre_img;

}
```

Y, en la parte del código donde quieras usar la variable, ***fuera de su ámbito*** , escribes esto:

```
$nombre_img=subirImagen(); //Aquí tomará el valor del return

$db->insertar(....);
```

Esto sería práctico únicamente si lo único que te interesa usar fuera de `subirImagen()` es el nombre de esa variable. Si necesitas otras variables deberías retornar un array con cada una de ellas, o, mejor, diseñar el código basado en una `Clase` para poder usar sus propiedades y métodos con mayor facilidad y tener el código más organizado.

---

### Algunas pruebas

Veamos algunas pruebas de lo expuesto anteriormente. Puedes revisar el código completo en este **<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/MXI15128)</kbd>**.

#### Prueba 1: como tienes el código ahora

No funciona porque se intenta usar la variable fuera de su ámbito

```
/*
    *Prueba 1:
        - No funcionará porque se usa la variable fuera de su ámbito
*/
function subirImagenSinReturn() {

    $nombre_img="imagen.jpg";
    $size_img="100kb";
}

subirImagenSinReturn();
echo $nombre_img;
```

***Salida:***

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: nombre_img in source_file.php on line
>   14

---

#### Prueba 2: retornando la variable desde su ámbito

```
/*
    *Prueba 2:
        - Se trae la variable llamando a la función, mediante el return
        - Recomendable en algunos casos, y si sólo interesa un dato de la función
*/
function subirImagenConReturn() {
    $nombre_img="imagen.jpg";
    $size_img="100kb";
    return $nombre_img;
}

$nombre_img=subirImagenConReturn();
echo $nombre_img.PHP_EOL;
```

***Salida:***

```
imagen.jpg
```

---

#### Prueba 3: obteniendo varios datos mediante un array

```
/*
    *Prueba 3:
        - Se traen varias variables en un array mediante el return
        - Poco recomendable, porque luego habría que buscar cada variable
          dentro de array.
        - En vez de esto convendría quizá pensar en una clase (ver Prueba 4)
*/
function subirImagenConReturnMultiple() {
    $nombre_img="imagen.jpg";
    $size_img="100kb";
    return array("nombre"=>$nombre_img, "size"=>$size_img);
}

$arrDatos=subirImagenConReturnMultiple();
$nombre_img=$arrDatos["nombre"];
$size_img=$arrDatos["size"];
echo $nombre_img.PHP_EOL;
echo $size_img.PHP_EOL;
```

***Salida:***

```
imagen.jpg
100kb
```

---

#### Prueba 4: Usando una clase

Aquí entramos en otro ámbito, pero muy interesante: Programación Orientada a Objetos (POO). Es un paradigma moderno de programación que te será de muchísima utilidad en un futuro.

```
/*
    *Prueba 4:
        - Mediante una Clase
        - Se declaran las variables como miembros de la clase.
        - Se puede acceder a ellas desde cualquier parte de la clase
        - Antes de optar por esta solución convendría informarse sobre qué son la Clases
          qué es la Programación Orientada a Objetos, etc. 
          Para no crear clases de forma indiscriminada
          La programación con clases es una potente herramienta para resolver
          problemas complejos, mantener el código organizado, evitar la repetición de código, etc.
          Algo esencial, sobre toco cuando se empieza, es pensar la clase como una entidad única
          no como entidades separadas. Así, podemos hablar de la clase Persona, la clase Imagen, etc
          las cuales tendrían todos los atributos de esa entidad como nombre, tamaño, color...

*/


class Imagen {
    private $nombre_img;
    private $size_img;

    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function subirImagen(){
        //Código relativo a la subida de imágenes
        $this->nombre_img="imagen.jpg";
        $this->size_img="100kb";              
    }

    public function insertarImagen(){

        $this->subirImagen();
        echo $this->nombre_img.PHP_EOL;
        echo $this->size_img.PHP_EOL;

    }

}
/*
    -Modo de uso de la clase:
       Creas una instancia de la clase 
       y tienes acceso a sus miembros usando la instancia
*/
$myImagen=new Imagen();
$myImagen->insertarImagen();
```

***Salida:***

```
imagen.jpg
100kb
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda hice lo que explicas aquí y bueno ya no aparece el error pero ahora en vez de insertar la imagen que le digo, pone un icono de X, y no las esta leyendo , y no esta insertando datos en la  base.
Muchísimas Gracias por tu ayuda pero bueno ahora es solucionar eso de la bd pero esta como imposible, voy a intentar algo a ver si conecta.

Comment: Parece que se trata de otro problema. Sí los errores por los que planteaste esta pregunta desaparecieron puedes darla por resuelta y plantear otra pregunta con los nuevos errores. Este sitio funciona por preguntas, para que cada situación pueda ayudar a otros usuarios con problemas similares.